# get web permissions list of a different site collection NOT using powershell or SOM

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, permissions

how to get the list of groups and people of a specific web in sp 2013 on premise. I do not have access to power shell. Also i need to get the permissions of the web in different site collection using java script. I can just add a content editor or script editor webpart in my site collection. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Please find below link this might fill your requirment

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163913.aspx